# What is a bijective linear mapping called?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Friedberg - Linear Algebra p.102

This book states that "a bijective linear map from a vector space to another vector space is called an *isomorphism*".

As far as know, generally *isomorphism* means bijective homomorphism and notion for this is $\cong$, NOT bijective linear map.

What is bijective linear map called? And what is the notion for this?

Comment: I prefer the category theoretic definition of isomorphism: An isomorhism is a morphism with a (left and right) invers morphism. Note for example that a merely bijective continuous map is not considered a topologicyl isomorphism (=homeomorphism). Alternatively, one always has to keep all those induced maps on the structure in mind ...

Comment: You might prefer it, but I think that Katlus is not into morphisms yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concepts are equivalent. You can show that in thi situation, a linear operator is a homomorphism, therefore, a bijective linear operator is a isomorphism.

Comment: @user62183 Thank you. It's off the topic, but how do i write "isomorphic into" and "isomorphic onto" in latex? Which look like --< and >--.

Comment: "In this situation" meaning "in the category of vector spaces"

Comment: @Katlus try searching here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdetexify.kirelabs.org%2F&ei=ZvAxUZ2TFI--9gThqIDABQ&usg=AFQjCNHJcuTHa35zBnkCkKDQZX2U9KjODg&sig2=W8q9-5D8jNX1uVREt2HUbQ

Answer (score 2):

More generally speaking, an isomorphism is a bijection between two objects that preserves their structure. The meaning of structure depends on the category you're working in.

- Sets: An isomorphism of sets is just a bijective map.
- Topological spaces: An isomorphism is a bijective continuous map whose inverse is continuous (thus, preserves open sets).
- Groups: An isomorphism is a bijective map that's a homomorphism (thus, preserves the group operation).
- Vector spaces: An isomorphism is a bijective map that's a linear transformation (thus, preserves the linear structure).

The list goes on. In your case, I will add that many times a vector space also has a topology (such is the case with $\mathbb R^n$, for example). In this case you'd be interested in an isomorphism of *topological vector spaces*, that is, a bijective map that's linear, continuous, with continuous inverse. It turns out that some of these requirements are superfluous :)

As for the notation for isomorphic spaces - I don't know if there's a standard one. It seems every book has its own favorite version of the equality symbol.